# How to return of the params to the backend (springBoot)?

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot

I am sending 2 params from the front end in the service below :

```
uploadFile(fileName: string, fileAsBase64:string): Observable<any> {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('fileName', fileName);
    params=params.append('fileAsBase64 ',fileAsBase64 )

    return  this.http.post('/api/uploadFile', params, { responseType: 'text' });
  }
```

But I receive  only one paramaters:
`fileName=test`
`fileAsBase64=null`

```
@PostMapping(value ="/api/uploadFile")
public String uploadFile(@RequestBody String name , String fileAsBase64) {
   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap your two parameter in a dto

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/api/v1/upload-file")
public String uploadFile(@RequestBody EncodedFile file)
{

}

record EncodedFile(String fileName, String fileAsBase64) {}
```

And you better version your api.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the @RequestParam annotation.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param

Comment: Still didnt work ! one of the param is null

Comment: public String uploadFile(@RequestParam String fileName, @RequestParam String fileAsBase64)

Comment: Dont forget the name must match, and you need annotation in both params

Comment: I am Getting ERROR 400 `"Required String parameter 'fileName' is not present",`

Answer (score 0):

you function have to be as the following:

```
@PostMapping(value ="/api/uploadFile")
public String uploadFile(@RequestParam String fileName, @RequestParam String fileAsBase64) {   
}
```

OR you can put any name but you have to put the matched name within the annotation:

```
@PostMapping(value ="/api/uploadFile")
public String uploadFile(@RequestParam(name = "fileName") String name, @RequestParam(name = "fileAsBase64") String file) {   
}
```

Comment: I am Getting ERROR 400 `"Required String parameter 'fileName' is not present",`